# Beautiful Soup - `findAll` not capturing all tags in SVG (`ElementTree` does)

Tags: python, svg, beautifulsoup, elementtree, choropleth

I was attempting to generate a choropleth map by modifying an [SVG map](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/USA_Counties_with_FIPS_and_names.svg) depicting all counties in the US.  The basic approach is captured by [Flowing Data](http://flowingdata.com/2009/11/12/how-to-make-a-us-county-thematic-map-using-free-tools/).  Since SVG is basically just XML, the approach leverages the [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) parser.

The thing is, the parser does not capture all `path` elements in the SVG file.  The following captured only 149 paths (out of over 3000):

```
#Open SVG file
svg=open(shp_dir+'USA_Counties_with_FIPS_and_names.svg','r').read()

#Parse SVG
soup = BeautifulSoup(svg, selfClosingTags=['defs','sodipodi:namedview'])

#Identify counties
paths = soup.findAll('path')

len(paths)
```

I know, however, that many more exist from both physical inspection, and the fact that [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) methods capture 3,143 paths with the following routine:

```
#Parse SVG
tree = ET.parse(shp_dir+'USA_Counties_with_FIPS_and_names.svg')

#Capture element
root = tree.getroot()

#Compile list of IDs from file
ids=[]
for child in root:
    if 'path' in child.tag:
        ids.append(child.attrib['id'])

len(ids)
```

I have not yet figured out how to write from the `ElementTree` object in a way that is not all messed up.

```
#Define style template string
style='font-size:12px;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-opacity:1;'+\
        'stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;'+\
        'stroke-linecap:butt;marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel;fill:'

#For each path...
for child in root:
    #...if it is a path....
    if 'path' in child.tag:
        try:
            #...update the style to the new string with a county-specific color...
            child.attrib['style']=style+col_map[child.attrib['id']]
        except:
            #...if it's not a county we have in the ACS, leave it alone
            child.attrib['style']=style+'#d0d0d0'+'\n'

#Write modified SVG to disk
tree.write(shp_dir+'mhv_by_cty.svg')
```

The modification/write routine above yields this monstrosity:

[image: Ugly Median Home Value by County]

My primary question is this: why did BeautifulSoup fail to capture all of the `path` tags?  Second, why would the image modified with the `ElementTree` objects have all of that extracurricular activity going on?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using BeautifulSoup 4.3.2, I ran `svg_soup = BeautifulSoup(svg); paths = svg_soup.find_all('path'); len(paths)` which outputted 3143. Perhaps you need to upgrade `bs4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alexce's answer is correct for your first question. As far as your second question is concerned:

> *why would the image modified with the ElementTree objects have all of that extracurricular activity going on?*"

the answer is pretty simple - not every `<path>` element draws a county. Specifically, there are two elements, one with `id="State_Lines"` and one with `id="separator"`, that should be eliminated. You didn't supply your dataset of colors, so I just used a random hex color generator (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14019260/1426065)) for each county, then used [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) to parse the `.svg`'s XML and iterate through each `<path>` element, skipping the ones I mentioned above:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import random

def random_color():
    r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    return '#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r())

new_style = 'font-size:12px;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-linecap:butt;marker-start:none;stroke-linejoin:bevel;fill:'

tree = ET.parse('USA_Counties_with_FIPS_and_names.svg')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    if 'path' in child.tag and child.attrib['id'] not in ["separator", "State_Lines"]:
        child.attrib['style'] = new_style + random_color()

tree.write('counties_new.svg')
```

resulting in this nice image:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Definitely an oversight, I was thrown by the pattern not corresponding with any specific boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the following:

- upgrade to [`beautifulsoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

  ```
  pip install beautifulsoup4 -U
  ```
- import it as:

  ```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  ```
- install latest `lxml` module:

  ```
  pip install lxml -U
  ```
- explicitly specify `lxml` as a parser:

  ```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(svg, 'lxml')
  ```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> svg = open('USA_Counties_with_FIPS_and_names.svg','r').read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(svg, 'lxml')
>>> paths = soup.findAll('path')
>>> len(paths)
3143
```