# How can I generate a random HTML colour in Python?

Tags: python, html, colors

How can I generate a random HTML colour (#ABABAB, etc) in Python? I tried doing something like

```
random.choice('0','1','2',)
```

etc. but it didn't work. Help? Thank you.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998901/generating-a-random-hex-color-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import choice

def colour():
    hex_chars = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    randomColour = '#'
    for i in range(0, 6):
        randomColour = randomColour + choice(hex_chars)
    return randomColour
```