# Random list from list with no repetition

Tags: python, list, random, python-2.x

I created a random list from a source list, the problem is that it has an item that is repeated twice. I would like to have no repetition in my list. Here are my code and the output.

```
COLOR_INDEX = ['FF000000', 'FFFF0000', 'FF00FF00', 'FF0000FF',
               'FFFFFF00', 'FFFF00FF', 'FF00FFFF', 'FF800000', 'FF008000', 'FF000080',
               'FF808000', 'FF800080', 'FF008080', 'FFC0C0C0', 'FF808080', 'FF9999FF',
               'FF993366', 'FFCCFFFF', 'FF660066', 'FFFF8080', 'FF0066CC',
               'FFCCCCFF', 'FF000080', 'FFFF00FF', 'FFFFFF00', 'FF00FFFF', 'FF800080',
               'FF800000', 'FF008080', 'FF0000FF', 'FF00CCFF', 'FFCCFFFF', 'FFCCFFCC',
               'FFFFFF99', 'FF99CCFF', 'FFFF99CC', 'FFCC99FF', 'FFFFCC99', 'FF3366FF',
               'FF33CCCC', 'FF99CC00', 'FFFFCC00', 'FFFF9900', 'FFFF6600', 'FF666699',
               'FF969696', 'FF003366', 'FF339966', 'FF003300', 'FF333300', 'FF993300',
               'FF993366', 'FF333399', 'FF333333']


#import random function            
import random

#create a random list of 29 colors .
color_lst= random.sample(COLOR_INDEX, 29)
print color_lst
```

And here is the result:

```
['FF993366', 'FF333300', 'FFCCFFFF', 'FFCC99FF', 'FF993366', 'FFFF6600', 'FF339966', 'FF003366', 'FF000080', 'FF0000FF', 'FFFF00FF', 'FFFFFF99', 'FF800080', 'FF00CCFF', 'FF808080', 'FFFFCC99', 'FF333333', 'FF333399', 'FF99CC00', 'FFCCFFCC', 'FFFF99CC', 'FFFF9900', 'FF660066', 'FF008000', 'FFFF8080', 'FF99CCFF', 'FFFFCC00', 'FF003300', 'FF800000']
```

Comment: I want to create a list with a specific lens ( usually around 25 ) from the original list which has 54 items, with NO duplicates.

Comment: Do you want to sample from the whole list or from the list-without-duplicates? These could produce different distributions. If you want to sample from the whole list, use `... = list(set(random.sample(...)))`. But if you want to sample only from the uniques, you should do `... = random.sample(set(...))`.

Comment: Look at that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998901/generating-a-random-hex-color-in-python

Comment: @mrvol this is a great question, I just can't find a way to create a random color that's not white, I guess in this line r = lambda: random.randint(0,255), I should change 0 to another number, am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want white, you can make it so `random.randint(1, 255)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list(set(yourlist))` to remove the duplicates. Since the elements are randomly generated, I assume that their order does not matter.

Comment: How do I define the lens of the new set using list(set())?

Comment: I meant length in my above comment