# Add random color to active object python blender

Tags: python, blender

Basically I want to add a random color to an active object in blender using python

I want to use random.randrange and i want the rgb- scale to start at 0.00 and stop at 1.0 with a difference of at least 0.3.

This is my code but somehow it doesn't work

```
r, g, b = random.randrange(0.0, 1.0[, 0.3])

mat.diffuse_color = (r,g,b)
```

Im new to blender and not sure how to this. What is the best solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, to generate a random color, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998901/generating-a-random-hex-color-in-python

Comment: Hm shouldn't you be able to get 3! different ways of combining the generated numbers 0.3, 0.6, 0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish the same with use of `random.uniform(stat, end)`, but here you won't get any option for skipping `0.3`.

So, it would be better to be with `random.randrange()` and here is the solution:

```
import random

rgb = ()
for i in range(3) :
    rgb += ((random.randrange(1, 10, 3) /10),)

mat.diffuse_color = rgb
```