# Get a Bright Random Colour Python

Tags: python

[image]

Hi all, in my snake game program, I need to generate a random colour multiple times when the user selects a "Rainbow" theme. After looking online, I found this:

[Generating a Random Hex Color in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998901/generating-a-random-hex-color-in-python)

The answer with the most votes gave a solution of

```
import random
r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
print('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r()))
```

However, this program generates very dim colours as well; for example dark brown and sometimes even black. As you can see, some of those colours do not match a rainbow-y theme.

How would you change the above code so that you get vibrant colours like bright orange, pink, red, blue, etc, you get the idea. A hypothetical solution was to increase minimum value of randint r, but that just made all the colours very white. :'(

Plz, plz, plz, help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: `random.randint(128,255)` will keep it on the bright side.

Comment: Another thing is when the three parts of the hex are similar (like #000000  or #ececec you get a grayscale color, so avoid those.

Comment: You could generate colors in HSV, with high saturation, then convert them to RGB. There's even a `colorsys` module in the standard library to do the conversion: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/colorsys.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create a random HLS color (using numbers around .5 as the "level" parameter and numbers above .5 as the "saturation" parameter) and convert them to RGB:

```
import random
import colorsys
h,s,l = random.random(), 0.5 + random.random()/2.0, 0.4 + random.random()/5.0
r,g,b = [int(256*i) for i in colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h,l,s)]
```

That will ensure you'll always have highly saturated, bright colors.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I made a few modifications to your code, but this definitely set me on the right track. Thanks to the handy dandy wikipedia page, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), and also a nice website [link](http://hslpicker.com/#0af529), I was able to find a good range of "saturation" (s) and lightness (l): yeah according to the wiki it's lightness.

Comment: @Lunkle Can you share the range of bright colors?

Answer (score 5):

If you start the random with a higher number the color will be lighter, for example:

```
import random

def random_color():
        rand = lambda: random.randint(100, 255)
        return '#%02X%02X%02X' % (rand(), rand(), rand())
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the hex codes of all your favorite colors in a list, and use `random.choices()` to select a random item from that list? I am using color names instead of hex-codes now, but e.g.:

```
import random

color_list = ["orange", "pink", "red", "blue"]
for i in range(9):
    print(random.choice(color_list))

# blue
# pink
# pink
# pink
# red
# red
# blue
# orange
# blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
import colorsys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
#generates random colors in semi rgb format


def create_blank(width, height, rgb_color=(0, 0, 0)):
    """Create new image(numpy array) filled with certain color in RGB"""
    # Create black blank image
    image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)

    # Since OpenCV uses BGR, convert the color first
    color = tuple(reversed(rgb_color))
    # Fill image with color
    image[:] = color

    return image
def random_colors(N, bright=True):
    """
    Generate random colors.
    To get visually distinct colors, generate them in HSV space then
    convert to RGB.
    """
    brightness = 1.0 if bright else 0.7
    hsv = [(i / N, 1, brightness) for i in range(N)]
    colors = list(map(lambda c: colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*c), hsv))
    random.shuffle(colors)
    return colors
colors=random_colors(100)
for color in colors:
    r,g,b=color
    r=round(r*255)
    g=round(g*255)
    b=round(b*255)
    image = create_blank(width1, height1, rgb_color=(r,g,b))
cv2.imwrite('path/to/folder'+str(r)+str(g)+str(b)+'.jpg', image)
```