# Trying to understand this bit of code

Tags: string, python-3.x, substitution

```
import random
color("#%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))
```

I'm having a difficult time understanding this bit of code provided as a response to a question related to random color generation. I have done a bunch of reading on string sub and I feel like I'm almost there but could use some insight:
[Generating a Random Hex Color in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998901/generating-a-random-hex-color-in-python)

"#%06x" < - reading an article on string substitution I'm seeing 06 indicating the number of digits and the x indicating a hexadecimal, am I correct in thinking that this is saying "convert the subbed integer into a 6 digit hexadecimal or am I way off?

% <- I think this is activating the string formatting with what follows.

random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF) <- When I run this independently I get a 7 digit integer but I'm not sure how this happens with a the given range.

To clarify I have two questions really: 
1. am I understanding what the string sub is doing correctly?
2. I don't understand the randint range and how a range of 0, 0xFFFFFF produces ad 6 char string

Comment: In theory you'll get up to a number up to 8 digits long (0 to 16777215), not just 7 as you've seen, but you seem to understand what the code is doing, I don't really understand what you're asking

Comment: Gives you a string similar to '#0a3ad1'

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: edited my post to clarify the questions I am looking to have answered

Comment: Okay, 7 digits in decimal (or possibly even 8), but how many digits will the largest value (0xFFFFFF) be when its in hexadecimal? Hint: it *is* in hexadecimal.