# How to create an HTML page that says Hello World n times in n different colors from python,

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to create an HTML page that says Hello World n times in n different colors where n is read from a config file in a different repository
and Spawn the page via python program
it would be more helpful we can use Javascript for the colors. I am able to display the hello world n number of times, but I dont know how to change the colors.
Here is the code I have written so far:

```
 import  ConfigParser
 import webbrowser

 configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
 configParser.read("/home/suryaveer/check.conf")
 num = configParser.get('userinput-config', 'num')
 num2 = int(num)
 hello = """"hello world """
 hello2 = hello*num2
 message = """<html><head>
 </head><body><p>"""+hello2+"""</p></body>
 </html>"""
 f = open('x.html', 'w')
 f.write(message*num2)
 f.close()
 webbrowser.open("file:///home/suryaveer/x.html")
```

Comment: Kindly share the code where you have tried to accomplish this. It will help the community in helping you out in your problem(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem

```

```
import  ConfigParser
import webbrowser
import random
def test():
    r = lambda: random.randint(0, 255)
    return('#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r()))
configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
configParser.read("/home/suryaveer/check.conf")
num = configParser.get('userinput-config', 'num')
num2 = int(num)
message = """<p style='color:{};'>hello world</p>"""
print "number read from file : " + str(num2)
f = open('out.html', 'w')
for i in range(0, num2):
    print message
    f.write(message.format(test()))
f.close()
webbrowser.open("file:///home/suryaveer/out.html")
```

```

Answer (score 1):

In order to style each "hello world" differently, they must be in different HTML blocks. You can achieve this wrapping each instance of "hello world" in a `span`.

```
hello = """"<span>hello world </span>"""
```

This will add no visible content to your page, but will allow each instance to be accessed and styled individually.

If you want to do it all in Python, you could add an inline `style` to the span when you create it.

```
colors = [color1, color2, ... colorN]  # List of n colors

hello2 = ""
for c in colors:
    hello2 += """"<span style='color:{};'>hello world </span>""".format(c)
```

Let me know if you need more help or want to know about other options (Javascript)

Comment: I need some more help :-) as because i want to take the input from a config file, like i want a output like, I want to enter the number of times I want to print hello world in the number of colors respectively, please help :-) and if u can state the other option(s) i.e javascript. It would be a great help      PS:  dont mind the english

Comment: Take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998901/generating-a-random-hex-color-in-python