# How to convert a random number into a HEX colour with python?

Tags: python, pandas, hex

Suppose I have a DataFrame with the following columns:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'strings': ['Wut?', 'Random', 'Citruna', 'FlatEarth', 'ElonMusk'],
    'postcode': [97700, 04130, 33210, 00520, 97700]})
```

**Problem:**
I want to create a new column that would take the values in df["postcode"] and use it as a seed to generate a random HEX colour. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example of how you could apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14019260/11989081) to your problem.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def color(seed):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    return '#%02X%02X%02X' % tuple(np.random.randint(0, 255, 3))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'strings': ['Wut?', 'Random', 'Citruna', 'FlatEarth', 'ElonMusk'],
    'postcode': ['97700', '04130', '33210', '00520', '97700']
})

df['color'] = df['postcode'].astype(int).apply(lambda x: color(x))

print(df)

#      strings postcode    color
# 0       Wut?    97700  #E60997
# 1     Random    04130  #FEDC98
# 2    Citruna    33210  #218F90
# 3  FlatEarth    00520  #AC6B9B
# 4   ElonMusk    97700  #E60997
```