# Colors assosiated with dataframe column in folium

Tags: pandas, folium

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
Lat  |  Long  |  Label
 x1  |   y1   |   id1
 x2  |   y2   |   id2
 x3  |   y3   |   id3
```

and I want to plot `Lat` and `Long` in a folium map, where the markers are colored based on the value of `Label`. The problem is that `Label` is a `string`. If it was an `int`, I could do the following

```
m = folium.Map(location=[21.37000, -158.08000], zoom_start=1000)
color_pallete = sns.color_palette()
color_pallete = sns.color_palette("Set2", 8000)
color_pallete = color_pallete.as_hex()

for index, row in test.iterrows():
    c = color_pallete[int(row['label'])]
    folium.CircleMarker([row['Lat'], row['Long']], fill_color=c, radius=2, fill=True, color=c).add_to(m)
```

Can anyone help me approach this when the Labels are strings? Ie. could I create another column of integers, based on the values of `Label`? If so, how to do that?

Edit: Just adding `color=row['label']` in the args of `CircleMarker` doesn't help, cause that way everything is a hue of black, not very distinguisable.

Edit2: changed labels to represent uuids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem, I used the following to create random color hexes,

```
color = "%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
```

as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998901/generating-a-random-hex-color-in-python/18035471) and then create a dictionary with the labels as keys, and the hexes as keys, to pass to folium.